# Programmatically remove files from Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal

Tags: iphone, .net, xamarin.ios

I am saving images and files to Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal. Saving a file is easy, but how does one delete a file?

I wish to delete files that my program considers old, so that I save as much space as possible.

I am using Monotouch to develop an iPhone application, but I believe this can apply to generic .NET programs as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
  File.Delete ( filename );
```

Where filename is `Path.Combine( Environment.GetFolderPath ( Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal ), "TODELETE.ext" );`

Using `Directory.GetFiles ()` you can get all the files of the folder.
Than get a `FileInfo` object from each to figure out size, creation date, etc.
Delete whatever you consider old enough.

Comment: the directory.getfiles() advice to get the fileinfo and creation date was extremely helpful. Thanks a lot.